# Async function but Await doesn't work in NodeJS

Tags: node.js, async-await

here's my function...

```
exports.createSomeFunc = async (param1, callback) => {
    for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        await anotherFunc(param2, function (err, result, request, response) {
            console.log(result + i);
        });
    }
})
```

For some reason I get "**SyntaxError: await is only valid in async function**" pointing at the Await line. What am I missing?

Someone asked what am I trying to do? I am trying to have the for loop wait at the function until it finishes before continuing to the next iteration. Here's another example:

```
exports.anotherFunc = (parm, callback) => {
    for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        asyncForEach();
        console.log(i);
    }
}
async function asyncForEach () {
    console.log("in");
    await setTimeout(function () {
        console.log("out");
    }, 100);
  }
```

This body of code returns the following:

```
0
in
1
in
2
in
3
in
4
out
out
out
out
out
```

so again the For-loop continues. How do I make the FOR loop wait for result of:

```
1
in
out
2
in
out 
...
```

Comment: what do you need to do? usually for not is use in node, you can use Object.values ​​(array) .map. what do you need, and we here can help you :)

Comment: @DanielLopez what do you mean? for loops are usable in node. and are prefarable for use for looping with asynchronous code in the loop body instead of forEach and map.

Comment: are you sure you did not mistype it in your first line? like
`exports.createSomeFunc = async (param1, callback => {}) => {.....` and ended up writing the code in your callback?

Comment: `await` ONLY does something useful when you `await` a promise.  Your function looks like a regular function that uses a callback and does NOT return a promise.  That's why `await` doesn't do anything in your code.

Comment: I can guarantee you that Async/Await works in Node. I use it all the time. You used await outside of an async function like the error says. For errors like this, it is better to copy paste your actual code instead of some approximation. One other important issue to mention is that if you're going to use await, you usually shouldn't use callbacks. Async await is for dealing with promises.

Comment: The very last character in your code snippet does not match any open bracket

Comment: Other than last unmatched paren this block looks fine

Comment: function asyncForEach() {
  return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 100, 1));
} , anotherFunc() should be async, and u should await the timer function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not waiting for setTimeout to complete. If you want to wait for each setTimeout call to complete in each iteration of for loop. You should use promise inside setTimeout and resolve only when callback is executed.

```js
const myFun = async(parm, callback) => {
  for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    console.log(i);
    await asyncForEach();
  }
}

function asyncForEach() {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    console.log("in");
    setTimeout(function() {
      console.log("out");
      return resolve();
    }, 100);
  })
}

myFun();
```

Answer (score -1):

the await is used for **promise**.

```js
const anotherFunc = async (oarams, callback) => {
  for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    await asyncProcess();
    console.log(i)
  }
}

function asyncProcess() {
  return new Promise(async (resolve) => {
      console.log("in");
      await delay(100)
      resolve(true)
  })
}

const delay = ms => new Promise((resolve) =>setTimeout(() => {
  console.log("out")
  resolve(true)
}, ms));

anotherFunc();
```

Comment: This is incorrect. You shouldn't mix async and new Promise... methods of creating a promise. const anotherFunc = async (params1) => params1 does exactly the same thing.

Comment: In general there can be good reasons to do `await new Promise(...)` - e.g. `await new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, 1000))`

Comment: I agree with you, but I did it for practical methods of the exercise :)

Comment: @DanielLopez your answer would be totally correct, if not for  the fact you added an `async` keyword to new Promise's callback method. I'm happy to upvote it if you edit and fix it.

Comment: You are right, the word async is unnecessary in the promise, but the solution is effective, I don't know why they voted negative, maybe they didn't understand it

Comment: @DanielLopez Async/await shouldn't work that way. because what if you don't have access to the "anotherFun" (e.g. it's from an SDK). In your code the res returned anotherFun is used in conjunction with the value of the i from the For loop. hence like to wait for anothoerFunc to return before increasing the i.